# Proving the product rule using dimensional analysis

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification, dimensional-analysis

$$\frac{d}{dx}(fg) = \text{?}$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}(fg) \color{red}\neq \frac{df}{dx} \cdot \frac{dg}{dx} \tag{units don't work}$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}(fg) = \quad f'(x)g(x) \quad \text{or} \quad g'(x)f(x) \tag{units consistent}$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}(fg) = c(f'(x)g(x)+g'(x)f(x)) \tag{$f ↔ g$ symmetry} $$

Now I don't know how to procede. I know that $c$ is adimensional and because of that maybe I could prove that it doesn't depend on $f$ and $g$ so it's sufficient to solve for $c$ by choosing arbitrarily $f$ and $g$ (like $g = 1$).

Comment: I could show you a proof not using dimensional analysis if you like.

Comment: No thanks it’s not what I’m looking for